# What is this plant (see the photo)?

Tags: species-identification, botany

EDIT: Found in Asia, China, latitude ~25 degree. Size about several centimeters.

I wonder what this plant is? It looks quite unlike the plants we see everyday. I have tried photo search engines and apps, but cannot find anything.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a fungus. Please [edit] your post to include location info about the photo and approximate size

Answer (score 2):

Possibly: **Genus Cordyceps (Kingdom: Fungi).**

Greater than 600 species of this fungus exist worldwide, their fruiting body's are club-shaped and range in colour from white to bright orange.

The spores being [entomopathogenic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomopathogenic_fungus), find an insect-host and proliferate within until the insect's behaviour is conditioned for the survival of the fungi. This has earned some varieties the name of the [Zombie Fungus](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/cordyceps-zombie-fungus-takes-over-ants) for the strange behaviour observed in inoculated individuals.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordyceps) indicates that is a part of the [ascomycota division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascomycota) which indicating it's reliance on a sack-like (or "wineskin") fruiting body to reproduce, just like common edible mushrooms.

Popular in Chinese traditional medicine and as a food supplement increasingly in other parts of the world, there is yet no conclusive benefit medicinally.

[Another photograph](https://pixels.com/featured/fruiting-bodies-of-fungus-cordyceps-sinclair-stammers.html), showing a cluster of fruiting bodies.

Answer (score 1):

In https://www.reddit.com/r/whatsthisplant/comments/qj0jj6/what_is_this_plant_have_used_photo_search_engines/ , @TinySpookyGhost mentions:

> I think it's a fungus. Maybe like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylaria_longipes ?
> Here you can see similar ones https://mushroomobserver.org/196852?q=2pXG

I think it is that one.